# ¿Como hacer que un repositorio, sea visible en GitHub pero que nadie pueda clonarlo o descargarlo?

Tags: github

Quiero que un repositorio pueda ser visible para todo el publico pero que nadie pueda clonarlo o descargarlo, a menos que yo le de el permiso.

De antemano gracias por leer.

Answer (score 0):

Según tengo entendido para hacer eso necesitas ser un Usuario de paga de Github ya que cuando tienes una cuenta gratis, tus repositorios son publicos.

Te dejo un link con al lista de precios https://github.com/pricing.

Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Creo que eso, es una función disponible solo en un repo privado, el cual en GitHub tienes que pagarlo, pero tienes alternativas como GitLab, en el cual, puedes crear repositorios privados de forma gratuita. Un saludo !

PD : https://gitlab.com

Answer (score 0):

Github hoy soporta repositorios privados en la versión gratuita, puedes convertir tu repo a privado y solo lo veran los colaboradores que agregues, si lo que quieres es que sea publico pero que nadie pueda clonarlo(No se si tiene sentido que sea publico pero que no se clone), eso es un feature que no está implementado.